# Не отправляются запрос с одного сервера на другой

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, sms

Есть сервер с PHP и nginx, там лежат файлы backend, там есть файлы PHP. В одном из скриптов верификации, PHP скрипт обращается к другому серверу, где установлен gsm модем и настроен скрипт на node js, который принимает данные http запроса от PHP скрипта из другого сервера, а затем отправляет СМС на указанный номер. PHP скрипт не может обращаться к серверу, где установлен gsm модем. Видимо проблемы с сервером, где настроен nginx и PHP, когда этот же скрипт я запускаю на локальном сервере, то она успешно обращается к серверу с gsm модемом. Помогите или подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема?
Благодарю заранее.

Comment: Каким способом отправляется запрос?

Comment: Проверьте настройки правил для файрвола. Может он не пропускает трафик, порты закрыты и т.д.

Comment: Никогда не надо спрашивать "в чем может быть проблема". Проблема может быть **в чем угодно**. Вы состаритесь раньше, чем дочитаете до середины списка. Спрашивать надо всегда "как узнать, в чем заключается проблема". Одна. Конкретная. Которая и стоит перед вами. А не которая "может быть". Начинать надо с **сообщения об ошибке**, которое у РНР есть всегда, если он не может выполнить какое-то действие.

Comment: Можно проверить логи сервера на наличие вашего запроса. Или просто пингануть его НЕ локально. Если ни то, ни другое не дало результатов, то проверить настройки файрвола, как сказали выше в комментариях